# How to access lower children using > operator?

Tags: css

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="c1"> Heading
 <div>
    <ul style="display:none">
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item1</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS :

```
.c1:hover > div ul
{
   display:block;
}
```

How do I access lower level children with ">" operator? I basically want the list to be displayed on hover of c1.

Comment: What you have done is right. What do you wanna do?

Comment: I have an asp menu. I want to use css to display it instead of jquery. Since its rendered as a list I thought accessing it this way would be better. But its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the inline style (`style="display:none"`) from your markup - inline style will override the styles loaded from the stylesheet.

Instead, put this in your stylesheet:

```
.c1 > div ul {
   display:none;
}
.c1:hover > div ul {
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this -

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MEWmA/1/)

```
<div class="c1"> Heading
 <div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item1</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul{ display: none; }

.c1:hover div ul
{
   display:block;
}
```